# CPU time of a process in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cpu-usage, cpu-time

Is there a way to know the CPU time of a Node.js process at any time? I need it to evaluate the consumption in terms of CPU time of some Node.js processes I spawn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sur of what you need, but if I understood you well I thinks you should take a look to `process.hrtime()` method, it gives you a diff between two calls, here is the [link](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime) to the documentation. Basicly you have to call it at the start of your process then call it again with the result of your function as argument when you want to make your diff.